# LogicalBinaryExpression to MemberExpression

Tags: c#, linq, reflection, c#-4.0, lambda

I'm building a repository class and my find/get/etc method accept the standard LogicalBinaryExpression `(x=>x.something == somethingElse)`

I want to be able to create fake out my repository and use the LogicalBinaryExpression and cast or convert it to a MemberExpression so I can use it to set the value my FakeRepository returns.

For reference here is the code for my FakeRepository.

```
 public TEntity First(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate)
        {
            return Builder<TEntity>.CreateNew()
              .With(predicate, true)
              .Build();
        }
```

Comment: LogicalBinaryExpression doesn't inherit from MemberExpression, so it can't be cast in that way.

Comment: Could you provide a sample of how you would like to use it?